# why the argument of a function are register type

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction, arguments

sorry if my accent hurts

In C Programming, you can declare a function like this:
dennis ritche 2nd ed page 84

```
 f(register unsigned m,register long n)
```

Most of the books say that the default storage type of function arguments are preferably `register`.

Why so? What is the need?

answer followed compiler keeps them with cpu registers but

I've not seen any difference in execution speed when using register type

Can any one explain in detail why and where and when exactly the register is used in C Programming?

thanks

Comment: `register` is not a type by itself, but rather a type modifier.

Comment: That's _almost_ correct, the correct term is type _qualfier_, in any case, it looks like you've got some crappy books.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: No it isn't - you have a typo :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError whoops, meant to give a reference to a language reference, which was from an incorrect spec, I was massively wrong, :-)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError corrected in my answer.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: Did you? - For me, "qualifier" is still missing the first I.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In my answer?

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: No in your comment above, but don't worry about it. Normally I don't point out people's typos - I was just messing with you because you said "the correct term is..." and then had a typo in it :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, well, I also had a typo in my answer, which I fixed, that's all :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'd be interested in seeing which books say this.

To be honest, at this point the state of compiler technology, there is almost never any use to declaring something with a `register` modifier.  In fact, many compilers will simply throw this out, and do whatever they want.  The point is that this varies so much across architectures, compilers, and is also affected by what kinds of other optimization are done by the compiler.  So, the choice of whether or not to store something in a register is a choice better left to the compiler and the use of the `register` modifier is usually considered an archaic antipattern.

EDIT: I incorrectly remembered `register` was a qualifier (which doesn't line up with the use of a type qualifier anyway, so I should have known), fixed...

Comment: yes i agree with my mistake the register is not a type but rather declaration of storage type.but my question is from the statement of dennis ritche at page 84 2nd edition

       f(register unsigned m,register long n)

register can only be applied to auto and formal arguments

my question is why ritche has decided to make formal arguments register type what is the reason behind.....

Comment: If I remember correctly, the register keyword can be used as a hint to the compiler to do this, but today's compilers usually simply disregard the qualifier.  (You may find some archaic compilers, or compilers for microcontrollers, which do not disregard it, but the majority of the "real" ones do.)